# cv2.kalman does not work properly

Tags: python, opencv, kalman-filter

I wan to use Opencv Kalman filter implementation for smooth some noise points. So I've tried to code a simple test for it.

Let's say I have an observation (a point). Each frame I'm receiving new observation, I call Kalman predict and Kalman correct. The state coming after opencv Kalman filter correct is "following the point". However the code does not work weel, it has no output which seems like an infinite loop in it. So can anyone give some hints, thanks. 
Below is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

frame = np.zeros((800,800),np.uint8)
last_measure = current_measure = np.array((2,1),np.float32)
last_predict = current_predict = np.zeros((2,1),np.float32)
predict = []
measure = []
X = np.array([[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0]],np.float32)

def move(x,y):
  global frame, last_measure, current_measure, measure, 
  current_predict, last_predict
  last_predict = current_predict
  last_measure = current_measure
  predict.append([int(last_predict[0]),int(last_predict[1])])
  measure.append([int(last_measure[0]),int(last_measure[1])])
  current_measure = np.array([[np.float32(x)],[np.float32(y)]])
  kalman.correct(current_measure)
  current_predict = kalman.predict()
  lmx,lmy = last_measure[0],last_measure[1] 
  cmx,cmy = current_measure[0],current_measure[1] 
  cpx,cpy = current_predict[0],last_predict[1] 
  lpx,lpy = last_predict[0],last_predict[1]
  cv2.line(frame, (lmx,lmy), (cmx,cmy), (0,100,0))
  cv2.line(frame, (lpx,lpy), (cpx,cpy), (0,0,200))
  print(current_predict)

cv2.namedWindow("kalman")
kalman = cv2.KalmanFilter(4,2)
kalman.measurementMatrix = np.array([[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0]],np.float32)
kalman.transitionMatrix = np.array([[1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,1],[0,0,1,0],
[0,0,0,1]],np.float32)
kalman.processNoiseCov = np.array([[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],
[0,0,0,1]],np.float32) * 0.03

for item in bound:
    move(item[0],item[1])
    while True:
        cv2.imshow("frame",frame)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a `move()` in

```
while True:
    cv2.imshow("frame",frame)
```